# PostgreSQL code optimalization

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    rv_storage.m_product_id AS n_product_id,
    rv_storage.value,
    rv_storage.name,
    m_warehouse.name AS warehouse_name,
    rv_storage.qtyonhand,
    rv_transaction.m_transaction_id,

    CASE WHEN rv_transaction.movementtype = 'V+' THEN movementdate
    ELSE NULL END AS last_in,

    CASE WHEN rv_transaction.movementtype = 'C-' THEN movementdate
    ELSE NULL END AS last_out,

    rv_transaction.movementagedays,

    CASE WHEN (movementagedays < -90) AND (movementagedays >= -180)  THEN qtyonhand
    ELSE NULL END AS more_than_90,

    CASE WHEN movementagedays < -180 THEN qtyonhand
    ELSE NULL END AS more_than_180
FROM
    adempiere.rv_storage
    INNER JOIN
    adempiere.rv_transaction ON
        rv_transaction.m_product_id = rv_storage.m_product_id 
        AND rv_transaction.movementagedays = (
            SELECT MAX(movementagedays) 
            FROM adempiere.rv_transaction 
            WHERE
                rv_transaction.m_product_id = rv_storage.m_product_id 
                AND rv_transaction.movementtype = 'C-'
                OR rv_transaction.movementtype = 'V+'
            )
    INNER JOIN
    adempiere.m_warehouse ON
        m_warehouse.m_warehouse_id = rv_storage.m_warehouse_id
WHERE rv_storage.m_product_id IN (
    SELECT m_product_id
    FROM adempiere.rv_transaction
    WHERE movementagedays < -90
    )
ORDER BY n_product_id;
```

That results in following table:

[table http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/4506/table3n.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/4506/table3n.png)

But on the server with live data (100k+ rows on each table ) it is too slow.
Can somebody tell me how can the code be optimized?

Thank You

Comment: Please post the execution plan (using explain analyze), as a link to http://explain.depesz.com and any index definition you have on the tables. Also check out this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions (And finally you might also want to consider re-formatting your query to make it readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery in the `where` clause is redundant. And I think you are missing a parenthesis in the `where` clause of the subquery in the inner join:

```
SELECT 
    rv_storage.m_product_id AS n_product_id,
    rv_storage.value,
    rv_storage.name,
    m_warehouse.name AS warehouse_name,
    rv_storage.qtyonhand,
    rv_transaction.m_transaction_id,

    CASE WHEN rv_transaction.movementtype = 'V+' THEN movementdate
    ELSE NULL END AS last_in,

    CASE WHEN rv_transaction.movementtype = 'C-' THEN movementdate
    ELSE NULL END AS last_out,

    rv_transaction.movementagedays,

    CASE WHEN (movementagedays < -90) AND (movementagedays >= -180)  THEN qtyonhand
    ELSE NULL END AS more_than_90,

    CASE WHEN movementagedays < -180 THEN qtyonhand
    ELSE NULL END AS more_than_180
FROM
    adempiere.rv_storage
    INNER JOIN
    adempiere.rv_transaction ON
        rv_transaction.m_product_id = rv_storage.m_product_id 
        AND rv_transaction.movementagedays = (
            SELECT MAX(movementagedays) 
            FROM adempiere.rv_transaction 
            WHERE
                rv_transaction.m_product_id = rv_storage.m_product_id 
                AND (rv_transaction.movementtype = 'C-'
                    OR rv_transaction.movementtype = 'V+')
            )
    INNER JOIN
    adempiere.m_warehouse ON
        m_warehouse.m_warehouse_id = rv_storage.m_warehouse_id
WHERE movementagedays < -90
ORDER BY n_product_id;
```

Now post the explain output.

Comment: ufff.. im new to this.. ok so I entered your code and from 35ms it went down to 6.. i don't know how you do it.. anyway, here's your explain: http://explain.depesz.com/s/inq

Comment: @MariánZekeŠedaj: your execution plan does not support your claim "*100k+ rows on each table*". It seems that most tables have something around 20-80 rows.

Answer (score 0):

**IN() and NOT IN() subqueries are poorly optimized:**
MySQL executes the subquery as a dependent subquery for each row in the outer query. This is a frequent cause of serious performance problems in MySQL 5.5 and older versions. The query probably should be rewritten as a JOIN or a LEFT OUTER JOIN, respectively.

Comment: Marian is *not* using MySQL and the PostgreSQL's optimizer is a **lot** smarter when it comes to sub-selects than MySQL